# How do I set focus on previous accessibility element after dismissing a modal view

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, presentmodalviewcontroller, swift5, xcode11.1

My view is constructed using stack view and model transition is setup using UITapGesture.  I have no data to update on previous controller. I just need to focus accessibility to previous view element after dismiss action. Currently after dismiss action the accessibility element is focused on navigation item back button. Which is like first element in the view.

Comment: cant comment on how to do this in xCode but on websites you need to store a reference to whatever item you want to return focus too. Then when you close a page / window / view etc. you manually set the focus back to the item that opened it in the first place. I would imagine you have to do the same.

Comment: @AshimDahai: The use of 'accessibilityIdentifier' may be a good lead to track to keep in mind the a11y element and then launch an 'UIAccessibilityPostNotification' to force VoiceOver read it out as the first selected element for instance? 